# I keep getting inf values when i run a function over an array

Tags: r, function, statistics

I am writing a function in R that will compute a sum of squares between a binomial distribution and normal distribution and display the data as a function of `p`

Here is what I have:

First I generate a random binomial distribution with probability p (n=100)

`random_binom<-rbinom(100,100,p)`

Next, I find the probability that some random element has equal or less than the value np (the mean) and the standard deviation of `sqrt(np(1-p))` according to the normal distribution

`d_norm<-dnorm(random_binom,p*100,sqrt(100*p*(1-p)))`

And then the probability that a random value in the distribution will have equal or less than the value of the mean according to the binomial distribution

`d_binom<-dbinom(random_binom,100,p)`

finally I subtract the two, take the square and return it.

`result<-sum((d_norm-d_binom)^2)`
`return(result)`

Now within the console, I created a function for all this:

myfunction:

```
function(p){
random_binom<-rbinom(100,100,p)
d_norm<-dnorm(random_binom,p*100,sqrt(100*p*(1-p)))
d_binom<-dbinom(random_binom,100,p)
result<-sum((d_norm-d_binom)^2)
return(result)
}
```

I want to pass in a vector for p where `p<-(c(0:99)/100)`, but whenever I do that, the function returns

`inf`

rather than a vector of values. How can I get R to return a vector of values so that I can plot them? I have tried using lapply but that returns the data in a strange format:

```
[[95]]
[1] 0.01064091

[[96]]
[1] 0.01418807

[[97]]
[1] 0.02647295

[[98]]
[1] 0.05065813

[[99]]
[1] 0.1179141

[[100]]
[1] 0.7342808
```

meaning each element is contained another element, making it very difficult to graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when `p` is 0, your function will effectively do this:

```
dnorm(0, 0, 0)
[1] Inf
```

Maybe you want `p<-(c(1:99)/100)`?

---

`lapply` returns a `list`.  You can use `unlist` to convert to an array.  Suppose you assign the results of an `lapply` call to `L`.  Then, you can do this

```
unlist(L)
```

Comment: Instead of using `unlist`, you could use `sapply` instead of `lapply`.